# Is it possible to clear the store cache for an app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

When a Google IAP is cancelled or refunded, it usually requires some time plus a reboot of the phone for it to recognize the item as gone. Is there any way to force that cache to check in with the store, or to clear it altogether?

Comment: Clear Google Play Store app data using application manager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear the "in-app billing service" cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618397/how-to-clear-the-in-app-billing-service-cache)