# autoRenewing: false when testing in app subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm testing my Android recurring monthly subscription.

I just looked at the receipt which I'm sending to the server and it includes `autoRenewing: false`, yet its blatantly a `$2.99/month` plan when you click order and it shows the dialog.

The only thing I can think of is this is because I bought the subscription then cancelled it, then bought it again to test. Maybe Google didn't properly set it back to active? Is it a bug, or something I'm missing.

I want to make sure it's working properly.

`purchaseState` is set to `0`, if that helps

Comment: Can you check and confirm if this could be because of local cache http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html? See how to clear cache here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618397/how-to-clear-the-in-app-billing-service-cache