# Refresh Play Billing purchase cache

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I'm using the Google Play Billing Library. The documentation for [`BillingClient.queryPurchases`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html#queryPurchases(java.lang.String)) says:

> Get purchases details for all the items bought within your app. This method uses a cache of Google Play Store app without initiating a network request.

Some customer support tickets have come in with receipts showing that they've purchased, and the Google Play Order Management console confirms this, but `queryPurchases` says that they haven't purchased.

I'm guessing that the problem is the cache of purchase details. Is there a way to refresh that cache in code?

(For that matter, is there a way for users to manually refresh the cache? Reinstalling the app and even rebooting the phone apparently doesn't fix it.)

Comment: I am sure how to refresh the cache, but purchase cache is saved in Play Store App's cache, not in individual apps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is not very good but you have to ask your users to clear data of the Google Play Store app, not your app.

Go to Settings -> Apps -> Storage.

And click on the *Clear Data* button.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15677062/9522887) answer for more details.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  The question asks how to "refresh" the cache, not how to clear it.  Are you suggesting that clearing the cache will cause the data in the cache to be sync'ed with Google's servers.  Because that does not work for me.

Comment: Exactly, The next time the user opens the play store it will look for data in the cache and when it does not find it there it will load the data from the servers. If this does not solve your problem then you may not have the caching problem.